# difference between @Reference & @References annotation in felix scr

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I am developing a OSGi bundle which used @Reference for service reference. While searching in Google i can see some examples using **@References** annotation at class level also inside the class only bind & unbind methods are used for all the Service references.

```
@References(
   @Reference(cardinality= ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_MULTIPLE, referenceInterface = TestInterface1.class,policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC)
   @Reference(cardinality= ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_MULTIPLE, referenceInterface = TestInterface2.class,policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC))
class TestComponent {
..
public void bind(TestInterface1 interface)
{}
public void unbind(TestInterface1 interface){}

public void bind(TestInterface2 interface)
{}
public void unbind(TestInterface2 interface){}

}
```

What is the difference between @Reference & @References ? Is there any performance measures/recommended measure to use @References? Since bind & unbind method names are same for all the Reference classes.

Comment: When talking about a Java type like `@Reference` it's important to show the full package name. There are many `@Reference` annotation types in different libraries and packages.

Answer (score 2):

In Java 7, it is impossible to define [repeating annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html). Therefore, a container annotation must be used.

@References is a container annotation that allows you to specify multiple @Reference annotations on one type. It does not have any performance difference. It could not have as these annotations are not processed at all at runtime (only by annotation processors at compile time).

Comment: Worth mentioning that `@References` comes from the [Apache Felix SCR Annotations](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html) (although not documented). The [OSGi Declaration Services annotations](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/cmpn/org/osgi/service/component/annotations/package-summary.html) do not include it.

Comment: Thanks Balazs. what about the method names of bind & unbind. Since i could see only bind and unbind for all the annotations defined in the container annotations. As Sean mentioned no where it is documented!

Comment: @Shiram: I am not sure I understand your question. The References container annotation does not have a bind/unbind attribute. The Reference annotation has. The Reference works in the same way if it is listed in an References as if it was put in front of a type. The  I suggest that you should check the javadoc instead of the documentation: http://javadox.com/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.scr.annotations/1.9.8/org/apache/felix/scr/annotations/package-summary.html